# webkit css transition not working

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm having a problem with my css transition animation. I'm trying to animate the transform via jquery. Everything works fine but the webkit-browsers. I don't want to animate the transform with a class, I need to do it with jQuery.
Here's the simplified code:

```
$(this).delay(i * 60).queue(function(next)
        {
            $(this).css({
                '-moz-transition': 'transform 1s',
                '-o-transition': 'transform 1s',
                '-webkit-transition': 'transform 1s',
                'transition': 'margin-top 1s,transform 1s,opacity 1s',
                '-moz-transform': 'rotateZ(100deg) rotateX(100deg)',
                '-o-transform': 'rotateZ(100deg) rotateX(100deg)',
                '-webkit-transform': 'rotateZ(100deg) rotateX(100deg)',
                'transform': 'rotateZ(100deg) rotateX(100deg)'
            });
            next();
        });
```

Comment: um you are doing this with css.

Comment: I'm sorry, I confused my code with a step function. I edited the text to fit the code and make things clearer ;)

Answer (score 0):

this line

```
'-webkit-transition': 'transform 1s',
```

should be

```
'-webkit-transition': '-webkit-transform 1s',
```

In this line

```
    'transition': 'margin-top 1s,transform 1s,opacity 1s',
```

margin-top and opacity are useless (with the code shown)

Comment: thanks, but this doesn't seem to work, I now get the rotation, but the transition with 1 second is not working. it just changes the css without animation